# How to change the capital D in the "done" button on the iOS keyboard using Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]

I want to change text of textInputAction options button in keyboard.
I want to set "Done" instead of "done"
i want to set d capital in done word

If you have any idea how to do that please suggest me